# Is it possible to forward Xdebug connections?

Tags: linux, phpstorm, xdebug, vhosts

I want to setup a kind of debug tunnel.

Setup:

1. Remote webserver running on a Linux VM
2. Two vhosts (H1, H2) on this machine
3. Both hosts have Symfony 4 running as WebApi
4. I use PhpStorm locally on Windows 10 as IDE
5. H1 is an API
6. H2 as well
7. Both want to communicate via cURL

If I make a Postman request to H1 or H2 Xdebug works great.

Now I want to send a cURL request from H1 to H2 and want to debug the request on H2 locally in PhpStorm.

As far as I understand, Xdebug will connect back to H1 because the request came from there.

What I want, is that it connects back to me, locally, instead of to H1 remotely.

Is this possible with my described setup?:

```
CLI Command on H1 -> cURL Request to H2 -> Xdebug locally in PhpStorm
```

Both vhosts use php7.2 and the same php.ini

Thank you all very much in advance

Comment: *"As far as I understand, xDebug will connect back to H1 because the request came from there."* Why? No. You need `xdebug.remote_host` to be `127.0.0.1` and `connect_back` option disabled (otherwise remote_host is ignored). As long as Xdebug will see that you want to debug this request (a cookie or GET/POST parameter etc) then it will try to debug it/make debug connection. If you cannot pass params: either configure Xdebug to autostart or use `xdebug_break();` in actual PHP code.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html -- Official How to debug using SSH tunnel. It clearly shows and hopefully explains how tunnel works. You both sites are on the same OS. So as long as you have SSH tunnel established (e.g. local 9000 --> remote 9000) then connecting on remote to 127.0.0.1:9000 will connect to SSH tunnel and will be forwarded to another side of the tunnel.

Comment: https://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-xdebug-and-firewalls.html Old original article from Xdebug author. Sadly I cannot find another article now with pics that better explain how it all works (it's more easier to understand it visually I think).

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I guess I didn’t explain it correctly. Both vhosts on the same remote machine communicate with each other (let’s say at ip 1.2.3.4) But I want to debug this communication locally in phpstorm at ip 127.0.0.1. The initial request is not sent from local but from remote to remote. Vhost1 sends a request to vhost2 and I want to debug that with xDebug locally.

Comment: So? What is the issue? It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around. It will connect where you will tell it to. It does not matter where the request comes from: from your local PC (remote for the host) or right there on remote (which is local  for the host). Xdebug/PHP is run on a server; locally you just need a debug client (PhpStorm in your case) and the source code. Reverse SSH tunnel handle the connection (forwards local Xdebug connection to your PC). The rest is a matter of configuring it. If you really have SSH Tunnel already working then I do not see an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @lazyone.

For me the right answer was to disable the connect_back Option.

Here the config

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = 192.168.56.1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
```

Your last comment helped me to understand it.

I didn’t know that xdebug always tries to connect to the remote ip, no matter where the request came from.

Remote in this case means: remote from the servers view and this is my local client.

It works now. Thank you very much.